# Url.Action how to convert utf-8?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url.action

">Şiir

`domain/Search/%C5%9Eiir` How can I convert it to utf-8?

`domain/Search/Şiir`

Answer (score 1):

Html helpers will always URL encode the values to avoid dangerous characters from breaking the routes. So you could either write a custom helper or hardcode it.